# How to get points coordinates on circle circumference with equal arcs length in unity

Tags: math, unity-game-engine, trigonometry

[image: unity get points on circle circumfrences]

Let's highlight some points on this image.

- N point coordinates (0, 0)
- A point coordinates (3, 0)
- The (ANB) angle = 30 degrees
- AB distance = BC distance = CD distance

Now, I want to get the coordinates of B, C and D points.
I can get every point coordinates by trigonometry (Sin, Cos ...), **But my question is**

Is unity engine provide any method to get point coordinates which lies on circle if I know the start point and arc length to the point which i need to get its coordinates ?? **i.e.** if i know the length of AB arc *-in upper image-* and A point coordinates, Can unity gives me the B point coordinates !? (of course i meant without trigonometry).

Comment: that's a vague expectation and would require too many arguments I highly doubt unity engine had a method just for that.

Comment: why not try trigonometry? it's common sense. btw the picture is wrong. D should be at (0,3)

Comment: A quick, though not optimal, way would be something like `B = N + rotate(A - N, 30°)`. Do you consider that included in Unity?

Comment: You mean an interface like the SVG path object provides with `getTotalLength()` and `getPointAtLength()`? From https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/API/SVGPathElement

Answer (score 1):

This is exactly the kind of problem trigonometry was invented to solve; trying to do it without trigonometry is just silly. If you are starting at point `(x,y)` on a circle or radius `r`, and you want to rotate by an angle of `a`, then the new point is at

```
(cos(a + arccos(x/r)), sin(a + arcsin(y/r)))
```

And if you need to implement these trig functions yourself, read up on their [Taylor series expansions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor_series#List_of_Maclaurin_series_of_some_common_functions).